# ionic header and subheader hides content

Tags: html, mobile, ionic-framework

I am developing a app for mobile device and i am using ionic. My problem is that i have created a header and a subheader but it is hiding the content.

My code is below, I hope someone can help me:

```
    <ion-pane>
        <div class="bar bar-header bar-energized">
            <h1 class="title">Delegate HR-System</h1>
        </div>
        <!--Sub Header-->
        <div class="bar bar-subheader">
            <h3 class="title">Add Employee</h3>
        </div>
        <ion-content>

            <!--Form add employee-->
            <div class="list">
                <label class="item item-input item-floating-label">
                    <span class="input-label">First Name</span>
                    <input type="text" placeholder="First Name">
                </label>
                <label class="item item-input item-floating-label">
                    <span class="input-label">Last Name</span>
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Last Name">
                </label>
                <label class="item item-input item-floating-label">
                    <span class="input-label">Email</span>
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Email">
                </label>
                <button class="button button-positive">
                    Create
                </button>
            </div>

        </ion-content>
        <ion-footer-bar class="bar-royal">
            <!--Menu-->
            <div class="tabs tabs-icon-top">
                <a href="index.html" class="tab-item">
                    <i class="icon ion-person-stalker"></i>
                    Employees
                </a>
                <a href="addEmployee.html" class="tab-item">
                    <i class="icon ion-person-add"></i>
                    Add Employee
                </a>
                <a href="addDevice.html" class="tab-item">
                    <i class="icon ion-laptop"></i>
                    Add Device
                </a>
            </div>
        </ion-footer-bar>
    </ion-pane>
```

Comment: If @Derry's answer worked, please select it.

Answer (score 4):

add `class="has-subheader"` to the `<ion-content>` element.